# $a,b,c\in N$ and $\frac{ax^4-bx^3+cx^2-bx+a}{(x^2+1)^2}$ attains minimum value at $x=2$ or $1/2$. The least possible values of $a,b,c$ are?

Tags: inequality

> $a,b,c\in N$ and $\displaystyle\frac{ax^4-bx^3+cx^2-bx+a}{(x^2+1)^2}$ attains
> minium value at $x=2,1/2$. The least possible values of $a,b,c$ are?

**Hint given**: Put $x+1/x=t$

If $x+1/x=t,x^2+1/x^2+2=t^2$

Let $\displaystyle\frac{ax^4-bx^3+cx^2-bx+a}{(x^2+1)^2}=y$

Dividing the numerator and denominator by $x^2,$$\displaystyle y=\frac{ax^2-bx+c-b/x+a/x^2}{t^2}=\frac{a(t^2-2)-bt+c}{t^2}$.

$y'=0$, if $t=5/2$. Thus $5(5a-b)=4(6.25a-2.5b+c-2a) \tag1$

I tried another method: $\displaystyle y'=\frac{(4ax^3-3bx^2+3cx-b)(x^2+1)^2-2(x^2+1)(2x)(ax^4-bx^3+cx^2-bx+a)}{(x^2+1)^2}=0$ at $x=2,1/2$

$\implies (4ax^3-3bx^2+3cx-b)(x^2+1)^2=2(x^2+1)(2x)(ax^4-bx^3+cx^2-bx+a)$

Putting $x=2$ we get $(32a-12b+6c-b)(25)=2(5)(4)(16a-8b+4c-2b+a) \tag2$

Now we can put $x=1/2$ to get the third equation.

We have three equations and can solve accordingly, but is there a shorter method since I only have $5$ min in the exam.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you used the hint. How would you write $y$ in terms of $t$? The minimum occurs at $ t = 2.5$ (on the appropriate domain).

Comment: @CalvinLin, I used the hint and got three equations, but it will take too much time to solve them. I'm looking for a shorter method.

Comment: (Right, you added that after I made my comment,) Can you check (1)? I got a different equation that you did.

Comment: @CalvinLin, yes I made the correction

Comment: Yup, now it matches what I got. See, you were close-ish, and just needed to push through. $\quad$ Note that your equation (2) seems off, since my solution set doesn't satisfy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ y = a + \frac{ -bt + c - 2a}{t^2}$.
Let $ c - 2a = d$ which is an integer (not necessarily positive as yet), so $ y = a + \frac{ -bt + d } { t^2 }$.

$y$ has a (local) minimum at $ t = 2.5$, which means that

- $y' = 0 \Rightarrow \frac{bt - 2d}{ t^3 } = 0 \Rightarrow 5b - 4d = 0$
- $y'' > 0 \Rightarrow - \frac{ 2 (bt-3d) } { t^4} > 0 \Rightarrow 5b-6d < 0  $.

Note: I've not guaranteed that this is a global minimum, but let's soldier on and come back later if need be.

Hence $ -2d < 0 \Rightarrow d > 0$.
Since $d$ is also a multiple of 5, so min value of $d$ is 5.
This gives us min value of $b= 4$, and $c-2a = 5$.
Since $ c - 2a = d > 0$, so the minimum of $a$ is 1.
Since $ c - 2a = d \geq 5$, so the minimum of $c$ is 7.

Finally, note that $a = 1, b = 4, c = 7$ satisfies the above conditions, meaning that the minimum of $ \frac{ x^4 - 4x^3 + 7x^2 - 4x + 1}{(x^2+1)^2}$ occurs at 2, 1/2, which [Wolfram states is the global minimum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E4+-+4x%5E3+%2B+7+x%5E2+-+4x+%2B+1+%29+%2F+%28+x%5E2+%2B+1%29%5E2) (and we should verify that), hence we are done.

Comment: I think the question says that the function is **minimum** at $x=2,1/2$ so we can assume it's the global minima

Comment: @Sunaina I'm just pointing out that I didn't use all of the information as yet. It might be possible that we still needed extra conditions to find the corresponding values (at which point, I would go back to where I have unused information. IE dig into what it means to be the global minimum). It turns out that we didn't need to do so. Note: Since we didn't use all the conditions, it was important to verify that the solution set satisified the original conditions.

Comment: I understood what you are trying to say, I was wondering if you could make the answer shorter by using all the information. I.e if you started by assuming the function has a global minimum at $2,1/2$

Comment: @Sunaina Not significantly so. The only way to ensure it is a global minimum is to check the values at all local minimums, and checking end points. While there is only 1 local minimum (which we showed), we didn't check the endpoints of the domain $ 2 \leq |t| < \infty$. This would require additional work (EG Showing that $ y(2.5) < y(2), y(2.5 ) < y(\infty)$. )